# why selector doesn't refresh into callback function after dispatching?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
    const signedIn = useSelector(signedInState);
    const handleSignInSubmit = useCallback(async() => {
        await dispatch(signInUser(username.value, password.value))
        console.log(signedIn)//always false, never became true
        if(signedIn)
          history.push("/")
        }
       
        }
        
      }, [dispatch,username.value,password.value,signedIn]);
```

so I have this code, initially the signedIn selector is false, but when I call the dispatch it became true, but if I try to console.log it into the callback after the dispatch he never changes state value(but into the store the value is changed)
why does it happen?

```
//action 
export const signInUser = (username, password) => async(dispatch) =>{
    
    const {
        SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCESS,
        //SIGN_IN_USER_FAIL,
    } = AuthKeys;

    var returning;

    var authenticationData = {
        Username: username,
        Password: password,
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: settings.UserPoolId,
        ClientId: settings.ClientId,
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username: username,
        Pool: userPool,
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: async function (result) {
            console.log("access token + " + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            await dispatch({
                type: SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCESS,
                payload: cognitoUser,
            });
        },

        onFailure: function (err) {
            alert(err.message);
            
        },
    });
};

//reducer 
const initialState={
    signedIn        : false,
    signedInUser    : null,
}
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    const {
        //Requests
        SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCESS,
        //SIGN_IN_USER_FAIL,
    } = AuthKeys;

    switch(action.type){
        case SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state,
                signInEmailData     : initialState.signInEmailData,
                signInPasswordData  : initialState.signInPasswordData,
                signedIn            : true,
                signedInUser        : action.payload}
        case SIGN_OUT_USER_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                signedIn        : false,
                signedInUser    : INITIAL_STATE.signedInUser, 
            }
    }
    return state;
}
//selector
    export const  signedInUserState=(state)=>state.Auth.signedInUser
```

this is the rest of the code , with some information on reducer and actions

Comment: You can see if the value changed in the redux devtools, there you can confirm the right actions are dispatched with the right values and cause the right changes to the state. I'm not sure what console.log is not working for you because I can't see any but I assume you are trying to log a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) You can solve the issue by putting your history.push in an effect.

Comment: yea in the redux dev tool the action change and signedIn became true

Answer (score 0):

`useSelector` expects a function to be passed in where you select the exact value from the store that you need, like this: `const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)`. I am not sure what `signedInState` is exactly in this context, you should provide more code.